# only to find herself **reciting for one**

Tags: phrase-meaning

> We, the successors of a country and a time where a skinny black girl
> descended from slaves and raised by a single mother can dream of
> becoming president, **only to find herself reciting for one**.
> And yes, we
> are far from polished, far from pristine, but that doesn't mean we are
> striving to form a union that is perfect.
> [Source: The Hill We Climb: Amanda Gorman's poem read at Biden's inauguration](https://news.sky.com/story/the-hill-we-climb-amanda-gormans-poem-read-at-bidens-inauguration-12888014)

Does "reciting for one" mean "repeating the dream of becoming president"?

Just a guess.

Comment: No.  It means "reading aloud for the President".

Comment: Does it sound "disappointing" or convey a sense of frustration?

Comment: No. She may have dreamed of becoming President, but she got to recite her poem in front of the President in real life.

Comment: I think the key confusion here is that "one" stands for "president," referring to the earlier phrase "dream of becoming president." It's like saying "When I was a kid I wanted to be a baker. Now I am one!" The second sentence means "I am a baker."

Comment: It's a clumsy bit of hack journalist tripe. In 99% of structurally similar examples, ***only to find...*** would mean ***disappointingly, only achieved...*** - something much less than had been hoped for. But in the cited context, it means ***Wonder of wonders!** Actually achieved something significant **in real life*** - as opposed to what had previously been seen as completely unrealistic "fairy tale dreams". Has any democracy yet elected a single mother to high office? Why bring race into it? The writer is perhaps thinking of JK Rowling as the role model, not politicians.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The sentence is from Gorman's poem, which, whatever you may think of its artistic or political merits, is not a "clumsy bit of hack journalist tripe."

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Please make your reply an answer since yours and Gotube's have both hit the high points that I was looking for.

Comment: @Katy: I don't think it *has* any "artistic merits". It just looks like politically-motivated doggerel to me. But regardless of that, ***only to find*** is clumsily used here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, your opinion was clear. But it's important to accurately represent the type of source material, even in comments.

Comment: @Katy: Granted. I didn't know anything about the source until long after posting my first comment. But it still looks to me like citing Greta Thunberg as an authority on climate change.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I appreciate the experience of having an immediate reaction, but the source was linked. It only takes a click.

Comment: @Katy: It only takes a click to discover that some people think this woman has "talent" (as a poet, a politician, or a civil rights activist, I'm not sure exactly). It would take quite a lot more effort for me to establish a case for saying she *doesn't*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recite):

> **recite** *intransitive verb*
> **1 :** to repeat or read aloud something memorized or prepared

She's reading out loud a poem she prepared for US President Joe Biden.

This may be confusing because this excerpt also includes an unusual use of "only to".

"Only to" is used to show contrast between expectations and outcome, where one is positive and the other negative, almost always where the expectation is positive and the outcome is negative.

Some natural examples:

> I tore open the box, **only to** discover that some of the parts were missing. ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/only-to-do-something))
> won the battles, **only to** lose the war ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/only))

This usage here is uncommon because the expectation of merely being able to "dream of becoming president" creates a *negative expectation*, and being able to read your poem during a President's inauguration is a *positive outcome*, which is the reverse of how "only to" normally works.

Comment: Your definition says _'especially_ positive expectations and a negative outcome', not that it has to be that way. Surely the contrast is between a vague dream and a real success?

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks. I hadn't read it that way, and that makes sense as the intent. I still think it's contrasting negative and positive though, rather than vague and real. Details in my updated answer.

Comment: I think the problem comes down to where the word "only" is put. The word in the original line "a skinny black girl ... can dream of becoming president, only to find herself reciting for one" appears misleading and it will become crystal clear when it is put immediately after "can": – "a skinny black girl ... can only dream of becoming president, to find herself reciting for one", which creates the dreaming as a negative expectation in comparison to actually reciting a poem in front of a president. Gotube has come to rescue the misplacement by adding "merely" in his explanation.